# Submit form mat-select date

Tags: angular

I have a form in which I can select a year, by default the current year is selected.

HTML:

```html
<div [formGroup]="formYear" fxLayout="column" fxFlex fxFlex.lt-md fxLayoutGap="0px">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
    <mat-select #selectedYear placeholder="Year" formControlName="year_user">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{ year }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<p>select: {{ selectedYear }}</p>
```

TS:

```js
selectedYear: number;
years: number[] = [];

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private msgs: MessageService,
  private sessionService: SessionService,
  private dashboardService: DashboardService,
  private router: Router,
  private uiUtils: UIUtilsService,
  private employeeService: EmployeeService,
) {
  this.selectedYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  for (let year_user = this.selectedYear; year_user >= 2020; year_user--) {
    this.years.push(year_user);
    console.log('selectedYear: ' + this.selectedYear);
    console.log('year_user: ' + year_user);
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    future_date: [],
  });

  this.formYear = this.fb.group({
    year_user: [],
  });
}
```

What I need is that each time a new year is selected it is collected and sent by GET to the back to collect it and use it in the queries.
The problem is that the log `selected_year` always returns 2021, selecting 2020 does not update. I don't know if I would have to add any other function to `onChanges`, but what I have tried has not worked at all.

I would need to send by GET / api / {user_id} / {year_user} but when starting the project I can't get it to send.

In addition, the back that collects the date is collected in the `DateTime` format, so the variable in which the year is stored would have to convert it into the `DateTime` format

Comment: so every time user select a year you want to trigger an api request with that value. Correct?

Comment: If that is, then collect it in the back, launch the queries with that data and reload the front with the requested year

Comment: that seems like many questions. Can you please elaborate only this question problem statement?

Comment: How I can pass `` year_user`` (one year) format `` datetime`` by GET to the back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `onSelectionChange` event to your `mat-select`. You can get the selected value using formControl value field.

```
<mat-select
      (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)"
      placeholder="Year"
      formControlName="year_user">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{ year }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>

doSomething($event) {
    console.log($event.value);
    //Make HTTP Calls using that value.
}
```

Working Sample: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-material-example-forked-62qp4?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: It's great, so if I can change it and collect the value. But, when passing it to the back, the disc expects a `DateTime`, now I need to know how to change `year_user: number` to `DateTime`

Comment: Date time is different. You cant convert a year to datetime. If I pass 2021 to back what is your expected datetime for this value?

Comment: In the select I can only select the year (2021), and the back depending on the year has to arrive (2021,1,1 (initDate) and 2021,12,31 (finDate)) to search the results in that date range

Comment: You don't need to pass dates like that. You can filter your data based on year also in sql query.

Comment: ah ok ok, so I just need to know how to pass 2021 as DateTime which is what the back Dto expects

Comment: I would say change your back Dto to number, pass the year into it. Handle the date at sql query level. Please accept the answer if this solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot change the input data of the Dto because other Datetime is already passed to it and I would have to change the rest of the project

Comment: you can create date object from selected year using new Date(selected_year,1,1) and pass that into your api.

Comment: How do I create that object to pass those parameters to it? is it a new DateTime?

Comment: Please raise a another question with require details and code which you have tried. Accept this answer if this solve your problem.